# GLMM indicates a negative trend, graph shows a positive trend

Tags: glmm

I'm analyzing my data in R using a GLMM, of the format:

`glmer(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+(1|site),data=df,family=poisson)`

This produces a negative trend for variable x3. On the other hand, the graph of this result produces a positive trend.

According to [the answers to a different question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/378874/regression-coefficient-has-negative-symbol-but-positive-from-the-raw-plot), this can happen if there is strong collinearity among the independent variables. However, variables x1 through x4 aren't collinear with each other, I've checked.

I tried similar analyses using lm, glm and lmer, and the first two produce a positive trend (matching the graph) while the third produces a negative trend. This suggests that the change in the direction of the trend is due to the random factor of site. A graph of the data seems to support this:

[image: GLMM graph]

What should I do in this situation? Should I be graphing separate trends for each site? I haven't been doing this so far because the effect of site isn't something I'm interested in.

EDIT: Here's the data:

```
Site   x3                    y
A2     -0.673                5
A2     -1.16                 4
A2     -1.16                 9
A4     -0.479                3
A4      1.56                 8
A4      0.00675              9
B2     -0.965               10
B2     -1.16                 6
B2     -1.16                 9
B5     -1.06                 6
B5     -1.16                13
B5     -1.16                 4
C2     -0.479               19
C2     -0.965                8
C2      0.590               10
C3      0.881               11
C3     -1.16                 8
C3     -1.16                12
D2     -1.16                 1
D2     -1.16                 3
D2     -0.0904               6
D4     -0.188                2
D4     -0.479                0
D4     -1.06                 0
E2      1.66                17
E2      1.76                27
E2     -0.188               32
E4      0.784                3
E4      0.784                1
E4      0.784                4
F3      1.76                 5
F3      1.76                 8
F3     -1.16                20
F4      1.17                 6
F4     -0.868                3
F4     -0.285                7
```

Comment: At least in my eyes, I can't detect a clear overall trend when looking at the x3 variable.
Also, when considering the individual site slopes for the x3 variable, there are more (and stronger) negative slopes than positive slopes.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you mean that the estimated coefficient of `x3` is negative, but you consider that your graph shows a positive relationship with `x3`. The estimate takes account of other predictors, but the graph doesn't. There is no contradiction there in principle.

Comment: I see about 20 data points and I can't summon up faith in a clear relationship with `x3` but as said the graph does not correct for other predictors. I would show a results table and make clear how many data points you have, There seems to be some danger of overfitting here.

Comment: @Nick Cox: I've added the data now. There's 36 data points.

Comment: Thanks for the data you showed. Someone was generous enough to upvote my answer -- which didn't purport to be a complete answer -- but I have to suggest that this thread won't become really interesting or useful for anyone, especially the OP, without more detail on the data (and context).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely to be Simpson's Paradox.

The estimates you get from a mixed effects model are the "within subject" associations with the relevant variable and the outcome. That is, the average for each subject. This can be very different from the overall association between the variables and the outcome. These can be, and often are, very different from each other. Sometimes they are the opposite sign and then it is an example of Simpson's Paradox.

If you want to disentangle the between-subject association from the within-subject association then you can do so with contextual effects - by group-mean-centering and including the group means.

Herre is a recent question and answer that goes into this in some detail:
[Understanding Simpson's paradox with random effects](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/479201/understanding-simpsons-paradox-with-random-effects/479217#479217)

Comment: Naming the problem is helpful.Your solution seems here likely to be successful only with a lot of data. Here there are 12 sites and only 3 data points per site and a more complicated model would, IIRC, add many parameters and bite hard at degrees of freedom. This is a problem for the OP, naturally, and not a criticism of the ideas in your answer. .

Answer (score 3):

There is very little context in names `y x1 x2 x3 x4` except that `Site` and your choice of language and command leads me to a  guess that this is ecological data.

This isn't really much more than a comment, but the graphs won't fit in any such. Referring to a Poisson distribution leads me to a Poisson fit of `y` on `x3`, graphed here, which does turn in a P-value of 0.010, stronger than I would have guessed from the graph itself. The fitted relation is an exponential and in this case approximately straight over the range of the data.

Naturally this fit says nothing about the other predictors, data on which are not accessible at the moment.

[image]

A graph separating the sites surely needs your subject-matter knowledge for interpretation, but it doesn't do much to help me. Some sites seem more heterogeneous than others, so what else is new?

[image]

This is the kind of armchair comment that is disappointing if not annoying, especially if your dataset in fact needed long and difficult hours to produce it: However, even with 36 data points rather than 20 as I guessed wildly, this is a rather small dataset to be fitting a complicated model.

People closer to your field should be able to say more if they were told what your variables really are. The full dataset or a printout of fuller model results might also allow more to be said.

I used Stata for the graphs, but they are, or should be, mundane in any language or environment worth attention.